# 500 Internal Server Error on Wordpress - BUT WORKS from a different country

Tags: linux, centos, php, proxy, wordpress

**MY MACHINE SPECS:**

I have a VPS (Location - Miami, 4GB RAM) running Centos and a LAMP stack.

I have Wordpress installed on it with a SSL certificate.

**PROBLEM:**

Out of the blue, the admin (/wp-admin/) area starts giving an internal server error when accessing from my country (India). The site's front end works.

But when I connect to the /wp-admin through my private USA proxy, it works!

Secondly, when I connect through my local connection, the wp-admin is **NOT** what I have customized (I have a custom admin theme), but rather the default wordpress admin screen (with the wordpress logo at the top).

Whereas, when I login from the US proxy, I can see my custom logo, background as it is setup.

1) So what could be going wrong with the server that it gives a weird 500 error for one country an works for another?

2) How can the page show 2 different admin pages (default theme vs custom)?

My host (who is in the USA) is unable to debug since they cannot recreate the problem from the USA.

Comment: Try browsing from a different device/network in your country. To rule out a bad proxy on your main connection.

Comment: Maybe Apache's mod_security + geoip is in use and requests coming from India/another country than USA are being redirected to some page, which returns 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: @JannePikkarainen If that might be happening, why is the front end of the site running as normal? Confused. :(

Comment: It's perfectly possible to configure mod_security to react only to certain URLs, such as `/wp-admin/*` and ignore the rest. Of course, not even mod_security is needed for this, one can create such rules with `mod_rewrite` with ease. First check if there's some strange rules in your `.htaccess` file in WordPress root directory (or inside the wp-admin directory)

Comment: Have you checked that DNS resolves the hostnames involved to what you THINK it resolves them to? Stale DNS caches can play nasty tricks on you...

Comment: Check apache error.log

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, the issue was caused by (and this is as reported by my host) some "code" in some plugins that are not compatible with php+APC cache...

Don't know if that's really true, but when we changed the handler back to suPHP, the issue resolved!

So for (future) people on wordpress + VPS, keep this in mind. If you are going to install some kinda opcode cache, be careful, and don't do it on a production machine...

Answer (score 0):

It definitely issue with your one of the plugin which you have installed in your wordpress website which is not supporting opcode cache.

I would advise go with plugin which contains cache settings and then uninstall it to test how website will work without the specific plugin.